# Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

Tags: android, json, eclipse, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I am new to develop an android application. I have read a lot of related post regarding the question I was asking but the tips or solution from the post did not solve my problem. (Looking for the solution for a week already, really need help in order to proceed with my project) Thanks a lot...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.aroma.slidingmenu.listener.JSONParser;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ResultListFragment extends ListFragment {
    
    TextView resultView;

    
public ResultListFragment(){}
    
    //progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    
    //creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> customerList;
    
    //url to get the customer list
    private static String url_search="http://192.168.1.3:80/test/getAllCustomers.php";
    
    //JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS="success";
    private static final String TAG_CUSTOMER="customers";
    private static final String TAG_FNAME="FirstName";
    private static final String TAG_LNAME="LastName";
    private static final String TAG_AGE="Age";
    private static final String TAG_MOBILE="Mobile";
    
    //product JSONArray
    JSONArray customers=null;
    //search key value
    public String searchKey;
    
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_searchresult_list, container, false);
            
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Search result in listview",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        searchKey = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), searchKey, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        
        //hshmap for listview
        customerList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        
        
        //Loading customer in background thread
        new LoadCustomer().execute();

        return rootView;       
    }
    
    @Override 
        public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            
        ListView lv =getListView();
        
        lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String iid=((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.FirstName)).getText().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
        });
    }
    
    /**
        * Background Async Task to load customers by making HTTP request
        * */
    class LoadCustomer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        /**
            * Before starting background thread show progress dialog
            * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());  //pDialog=new ProgressDialog(ResultListFragment.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading customers. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        
        /**
            * getting customers url
            * **/
        protected String doInBackground(String... args){
            //Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //value captured from previous intent
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FirstName", searchKey));
            //getting JSON string from url
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_search, "GET", params);
            //check your log cat for JSON response
            Log.d("Search customer", json.toString());
            
            try{
                //checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success=json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                
                if(success==1){
                    //product found
                    //Getting array of products
                    customers=json.getJSONArray(TAG_CUSTOMER);
                    
                    //looping through all products
                    for(int i=0;i<customers.length();i++){
                        JSONObject c=customers.getJSONObject(i);
                        
                        //storing each json item in variable
                        String fname=c.getString(TAG_FNAME);
                        String lname=c.getString(TAG_LNAME);
                        String age=c.getString(TAG_AGE);
                        String mobile=c.getString(TAG_MOBILE);
                        
                        //creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                        
                        //adding each child node to HashMap key =>value
                        map.put(TAG_FNAME, fname);
                        map.put(TAG_LNAME, lname);
                        map.put(TAG_AGE, age);
                        map.put(TAG_MOBILE, mobile);
                        
                        //adding HashList to ArrayList
                        customerList.add(map);
                    }
                }else{
                        //no customer found
                        //do sth
                    Handler handler =  new Handler(getActivity().getMainLooper());
                    handler.post( new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"no customer found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        }
                    });
                    }
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                //return "success";
                return null;
            }
        
        /**
            * After completing background task dismiss the progress dialog
            * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
            //dimiss the dialog after getting the related customer
            pDialog.dismiss();
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    /**
                        * updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                        * **/
                    ListAdapter adapter =new SimpleAdapter(
                            getActivity(), customerList, 
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ TAG_FNAME, TAG_LNAME, TAG_AGE, TAG_MOBILE},
                            new int[]{R.id.FirstName,R.id.LastName,R.id.Age,R.id.Mobile});
                        //updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
    
    
}
```

JSONParser.java

```
package com.example.aroma.slidingmenu.listener;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            
            // check for request method
            if(method.equals("POST")){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                
            }else if(method.equals("GET")){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                //is = httpEntity.getContent();
                
                String all=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    Log.d("response",all);
            }           
            

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }       
}
```

getAllCustomers.php

```
$response = array();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db("testdatabase", $con);

$FirstName=$_GET["FirstName"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer where FirstName like '%$FirstName%' ");


if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["customers"] = array();
    
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $customers = array();
        $customers["FirstName"] = $row["FirstName"];
        $customers["LastName"] = $row["LastName"];
        $customers["Age"] = $row["Age"];
        $customers["Mobile"] = $row["Mobile"];
    
        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["customers"], $customers);
}
// success
    $response["success"] = 1;
        // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";
    
    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Error that I saved from Logcat:

```
02-12 17:17:50.599: E/Buffer Error(13636): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
02-12 17:17:50.599: E/JSON Parser(13636): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.example.aroma.slidingmenu.ResultListFragment$LoadCustomer.doInBackground(ResultListFragment.java:136)
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at com.example.aroma.slidingmenu.ResultListFragment$LoadCustomer.doInBackground(ResultListFragment.java:1)
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-12 17:17:50.604: E/AndroidRuntime(13636):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: you can also able to check why getting NPE in line number `136` in ResultListFragment ?

Comment: line number 136 is Log.d("Search customer:",json.toString()); 
if NPE means, json.toString() got null value?

Comment: yes `json` is `null` check what you are getting `json = sb.toString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try call asynctask in `onActivityCreated`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_searchresult_list, container, false);         

    return rootView;       
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Search result in listview",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    searchKey = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), searchKey, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //hshmap for listview
    customerList= new ArrayList>();


    //Loading customer in background thread
    new LoadCustomer().execute();

}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to call asynctask in onActivityCreated but same errors encountered.

Comment: Hi again... hehe.. I found out a problem and I'm not sure why does this happened. I tried to debug my application in genymotion with the code above and got the expected output. But when it goes with an android device, Buffer Error and Parser error were caught.  I have to reboot my pc and re-run the application with my device, the problem solved. But this problem seems to pop out inconsistently.

Comment: I prefer testing with real android device and real url. With emulator or localhost wamp mysql server i have the similary problems